# golang, статическая типизация и json

Tags: json, golang

У меня есть json ответ от сервера в виде строки. Я его раскладываю через `json.Unmarshal` в переменную `body` с типом `map[string]interface{}`.

```
var body map[string]interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(bodyByte, &body); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Теперь мне надо достать из `body["items"]` первый элемент, но тут возникает проблема:

`Invalid operation: 'body["items"][0]' (type 'interface{}' does not support indexing)`

На go я пишу не много (в основном python), так что у меня появился вопрос: Как объяснить go, что в `body` есть элементы с разными типами (`map[string]string`, `[]string`, `string` и т.д)

Comment: `body["items"].([]string)[0]`

Comment: https://go.dev/tour/methods/15

Comment: https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/type-assertions-vs-type-conversions/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если у вас заранее известна структура ответа, то вы можете сделать статический тип Go. Тогда `Unmarshal` будет сам конвертировать типы из `json` в `go`.

```
type Response struct {
    Code  int      `json:"code"`
    Items []string `json:"items"`
}
```

Пример декодирования:

```
data := []byte(`{"code":200,"items":["Alice","Bob", "Charlie"]}`)
var rsp Response
err := json.Decode(data, &rsp)
if err != nil { panic(err) }
fmt.Println(rsp.Items[0])
```

О том, как `encoding/json` интепретирует тег `json:"..."` см. документацию https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal